Is there a way to shutdown the PC after playing on the Steam for a long time?
Sometimes I leave Steam that is running PalWorld overnight, for some Ore or Coal mining going on in the background.
But then after I quit the game and Steam, the PC always had problem restarting or shutting down. (if I choose Restart, it does nothing at all, or show "Restarting" for 30 minutes or more without saying it is doing Windows Update. If I choose "Shutdown", then the whole computer froze up).
So I had to wait a couple of minutes, and then long press the power button on the PC to force shut it down, and then restart the computer.
Usually, it is considered not a good procedure to force shutdown, as it can possibly corrupt the hard drive or the operating system (Windows 11).
By the way, CTRL-ALT-DEL doesn't work either.
So right now, I have to force shut down every other day, so in a year, I will have forced shut down about 180 times, and the PC and Windows 11 can be in a bad shape.
This happens on both my Lenovo Gaming PC and the Dell Alienware Gaming PC (purchased within 18 months and 1 month respectively).
Is there a way to restart or shutdown the PC properly after running Steam for a long time?

You should investigate why the pc crashes instead of trying to find ways to solve your workaround.

Shouldn't he like let more then a minute for windows to update? Who knows what it is doing, dont force shutdowns if your pc works normally during your day on it, if it takes 30mins once ever 6mo's, it is ok ;)

It is not showing "Updating: Don't turn off the PC". It is just not doing anything at all if I choose Restart, for 20 or 30 minutes. And when I choose Shutdown, then the whole computer froze

Have you tried shutting down with the command shutdown /s /t 00 ?
